# This console app code runs once then close when i hit enter but i need it to be continious wht would i change?

Tags: c#

My goal is to have the user input a number then add 5 to that number then display result to user and I want this to occur more than once

```
class Program
{
    public Queue VisitedQueue = new Queue();
    public Program myprogram = new Program();
    static void Main()
    {
        int M = Main1();
        Console.WriteLine(M); // display M
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static int Main1()//get user number input and add 5 store as M
    {
        string H;
        int M;
        H = Console.ReadLine();
        M = Convert.ToInt32(H) + 5;
        return M;

    }
}
```

Comment: Use a [`while` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/while).

Comment: I suggest you to read up on `loops` something like a `for` loop, a `while` loop or a `foreach` loop, just some examples :)

Comment: @Ahmed Abdelhameed would you demonstrate how i would implement my loop?, would it be implemented in main method or my custom method?

Comment: @tre3y You don't really need a second method unless you have a reason to (e.g., for refactoring reasons). Check the linked question for guidance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I want this to occur more than once.

for achieving this goal you have to use `loop` in `c#`. for learning, loops follow this [link](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-for-loop).

and for this scenario that you define in question, you can try below code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter repeat time:");
        var counter = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (var i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your number:");
            var number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine($"{number} + 5 = {number +5}");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

feel free to ask questions. good luck